# SingletonBean with PrototypeBean dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection

I am learning the scope dependency of injected beans in Spring framework. I was learning to solve the narrow scope bean dependency from websites. But I am not able to see the resolution as explained in the websites. I have tried using the method of Inject ApplicationContext bean into MySingletonBean to get instance of MyPrototypeBean. However I do not see any difference in the  bean creation.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.learning.spring.basics.scope.proxy")
public class SpringScopeProxyApplication {
    public static void main(String...strings) throws InterruptedException {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringScopeProxyApplication.class, strings);
        SingletonBean bean1=ctx.getBean(SingletonBean.class);
        /**
         * Singleton bean is wired with a proototypeBean. But since a singleton bean is created only once by the container
         *  even the autowired proptotyeBean is also created once. 
         */

        bean1.display();

        SingletonBean bean2=ctx.getBean(SingletonBean.class);
        bean2.display();
    }

}


@Component
public class SingletonBean {
    @Autowired
    // prototypeBean is of scope prototype injected into singleton bean
    private PrototypeBean prototypeBean;

    //Fix 1 - Inject ApplicationContext and make the singletonbean applicationcontextaware

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public PrototypeBean getPrototypeBean() {
        return prototypeBean;
    }

    public void setPrototypeBean(PrototypeBean prototypeBean) {
        this.prototypeBean = prototypeBean;
    }


    // Fix -1 - get the prototypeBean object from applicationContext everytime the method is called
    public void display() {
        applicationContext.getBean(PrototypeBean.class).showTime();
        //prototypeBean.showTime();
    }

    PrototypeBean

package com.learning.spring.basics.scope.proxy;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class PrototypeBean {

    public void showTime() {
        System.out.println("Time is "+LocalDateTime.now().toString());
    }
}
```

Expected Results:The time stamp should be different as the prototype scoped bean should be a new instance
Actual results: The timestamps are same with no difference

Answer (score 0):

This is not right way to validate `SCOPE_PROTOTYPE` bean because `showTime` is an instance methods that gets executed when you invoke it through object so you will always get the different timestamp.But i'm not sure how you are getting same timestamp, but below is an example

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.learning.spring.basics.scope.proxy")
public class SpringScopeProxyApplication {
public static void main(String...strings) throws InterruptedException {
    ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(SpringScopeProxyApplication.class, strings);
    SingletonBean bean1=ctx.getBean(PrototypeBean.class);
     System.out.println(bean1);

    SingletonBean bean2=ctx.getBean(PrototypeBean.class);
     System.out.println(bean2);
     }

 }
```

You will get the two different object references

```
com.learning.spring.basics.scope.proxy.PrototypeBean@48976e6d
com.learning.spring.basics.scope.proxy.PrototypeBean@2a367e93
```